# NestJS CLI MODULE_NOT_FOUND with Docker

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, docker-compose, nestjs

I'm implementing a **NestJS** microservices project in a monorepo structure. Suppose that I have two microservices that have the same **Dockerfiles**, and I am running the project using a **docker-compose** file. the docker-compose file is as follows:

```
services:
  firstMicroservice:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./apps/firstMicroservice/Dockerfile
      target: development
    command: pnpm run start:dev firstMicroservice
    env_file:
      - ./apps/firstMicroservice/.env
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
  auth:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./apps/auth/Dockerfile
      target: development
    command: pnpm run start:dev auth
    env_file:
      - ./apps/auth/.env
    ports:
      - '3001:3001'
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app    
  mongo:
    image: mongo
```

Then here is my Dockerfile (as an example of my Dockerfiles):

```
FROM node:alpine As development

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json ./
COPY pnpm-lock.yaml ./

RUN npm install -g pnpm
RUN npm install -g @nestjs/cli
RUN pnpm install

COPY . .

RUN pnpm run build

FROM node:alpine as production

ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json ./
COPY pnpm-lock.yaml ./

RUN npm install -g pnpm
RUN npm install -g @nestjs/cli
RUN pnpm install --prod 

COPY --from=development /usr/src/app/dist ./dist

CMD ["node", "dist/apps/auth/main"]
```

The problem is that when I run docker-compose up I get this error:

```
auth-1   | > nest start --watch "auth"
auth-1   |
auth-1   | node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
auth-1   |   throw err;
auth-1   |   ^
auth-1   |
auth-1   | Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/bin/nest.js'
auth-1   |     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
auth-1   |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
auth-1   |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] 
(node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
auth-1   |     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
auth-1   |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
auth-1   |   requireStack: []
auth-1   | }
auth-1   |
auth-1   | Node.js v21.4.0
auth-1   |  ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
```

The interesting thing is that when I change the **WORKDIR** in the Dockerfile to **/app** instead of **usr/src/app** the error is not showing anymore and the application works. but in this case, if I change the **volumes** address in the **docker-compose** to **/app** too, the error shows up again.

As much as I know these two addresses should be the same but when they are the same I get the error about **not finding** the **nestjs cli module**. also when I change the address to /app, I don't have **hot reloading** anymore and I think something is wrong with this solution.

**I would appreciate it if anyone could help or if you give me any idea about this**. also, I want to know other than hot reloading that I miss, **what problem it might cause** if these **two addresses are not the same**.

Comment: I'd recommend deleting the Compose `volumes:` blocks entirely: they are hiding everything the image build does, and causing this problem.  You shouldn't need to override the `command:` either.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you for your response. could you please explain more about this? what do you mean by "they are hiding everything the image build does"? 
as I know these volume mounts are often used during development to enable hot-reloading of code changes, then how can I use docker-compose with hot reloading during the development phase?

Comment: I'd just use Node here, without involving Docker at all.  That sentence means literally what it says: your image could delete everything in `/app`, and the bind mount would replace the entire image contents with the host directory.  This setup is basically equivalent to using the unmodified `node` image with a bind mount, which in turn is the same as just running Node except with an isolation layer in between your code and the language runtime.